# Flutter practice project ideas for state management / HTTP usage / dependency injection learning

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some experience with flutter so I'm not a complete beginner but not yet at an advanced level, and I would like to improve.

I'm looking to get familiar with advanced state management (Riverpod or Bloc), HTTP networking, dependency injection and maybe RxDart as well.

Can you recommend some exercise project ideas where I could cover the topics mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a movie discovery app api from TMDP API and state management you can choose what you want either bloc or GETX.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).